# Spring batch - unable to delete from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE using H2

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, spring-batch, h2

I'm trying to write a job to cleanup the Spring batch metadata tables (as defined here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql) which I currently have in an embedded H2 DB. All delete queries are being executed successfully working backwards from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT, however, the last query is failing with `Invalid value "1" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-200]`

This is the query being executed to delete from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE:

`DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE WHERE JOB_INSTANCE_ID NOT IN (SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION)`

Any ideas why this might be failing?

List of all queries:

```
private static final String SQL_DELETE_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT = "DELETE FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where CREATE_TIME < ?))";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION = "DELETE FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where CREATE_TIME < ?)";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT = "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where CREATE_TIME < ?)";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS = "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where CREATE_TIME < ?)";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION = "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where CREATE_TIME < ?";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE = "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE WHERE JOB_INSTANCE_ID NOT IN (SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION)";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did not specify your deletion queries. Are you intending to remove all meta-data or a just a subset? The correct sequence to delete all meta-data can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/test/JobRepositoryTestUtils.java#L204-L219.

Comment: Your last query is not clear to me: `DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE WHERE JOB_INSTANCE_ID NOT IN (SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION)`. Are you trying to remove "orphan" job instances (ie job instances that do not have job executions)?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank you for your input. The idea is to delete job data older than say a week to maintain only recent job data. BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION has already had old data cleaned up, and therefore there would be old job data in BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE that does not exist in BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, hence the query. I did not think the other deletion queries were relevant since they are executing without issue, however, I can provide them if that would be helpful.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I adjusted the queries to what you suggested, and simply tried removing all metadata from the batch tables, however, I was met with the following error: `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [DELETE FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT]; Invalid value "1" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-200];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was passing a date parameter to all delete queries executed with jdbc template, however, as you can in the last delete query there is no parameter required.

Once I removed the parameter from the jdbc template update method the query ran fine.